# select all input elements but not the current one

Tags: javascript, jquery, meteor

This Meteor client `Template.abc.events` code tries to apply a class on all input element but not the one which fired the event.
I it not doing so, how can it be fixed? Thanks

```js
  'click input[name="a.b"]': function(event) {
    $('input:not($(event.target))').each(function(element) {
      $(element).addClass('inactive');
    })
  }
```

Comment: You don't need `.each()`. You can call `.addClass` directly on the collection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(event.target)` is a string and is not evaluated, it will be treated as a selector. You can use the `.not` method that excludes the passed element(s) from the set:

```
$('input').not(event.target).each(fn);
```

Also note that the first parameter of the `.each` callback is the index. Your `each` loop fails to select the current item of the iteration. You should use either the second parameter of the callback or the `this` keyword. However, as `.addClass` iterates through the collection there is no need to use the `.each` method. You can simply call the `.addClass` on the set.

Answer (score 0):

Try this `$('input').not(event.target)`

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `input:not(:focus)` for that:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input').click(function() {
        $(this).removeClass('inactive');
        $('input:not(:focus)').addClass('inactive');
    });
});
```

Working sample:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('input').click(function() {
    $(this).removeClass('inactive');
    $('input:not(:focus)').addClass('inactive');
  });
});
```

```css
.inactive {
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input />
<input />
<input />
<input />
```